# Why IntentReceiverLeaked?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I want to receive a `String` from the Bluetooth server which is pc I have a java code for it but when ever I run my Android client `Activity` it shows me this exception

```
Activity com.waseem.mobileclient.bluetoot_app.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.waseem.mobileclient.bluetoot_app.MainActivity$1@410480f0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.waseem.mobileclient.bluetoot_app.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.waseem.mobileclient.bluetoot_app.MainActivity$1@410480f0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:792)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:593)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1111)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1098)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1092)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:365)
        at com.waseem.mobileclient.bluetoot_app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
```

I am unregistering in `onPause()` why I am getting this exception please help me out It has stuck me for a long time.
here is the client code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (myBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "No Bluetooth Adapter available. Exiting...");
        this.finish();
    }
    IntentFilter intent_filter=new IntentFilter(MESSAGE_RECEIVED_INTENT);
    broad_receiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(MESSAGE_RECEIVED_INTENT)) {
                showInformation(intent.getExtras().getString("Message"), 5000);
                getVibrator().vibrate(500);
            }
            else {
                showInformation("Message unable to receive", 5000);
                getVibrator().vibrate(500);
            }
        }
    };

    this.registerReceiver(broad_receiver,intent_filter);
    Button start_server = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_start);
    start_server.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button stop_server = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
    stop_server.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    this.unregisterReceiver(this.broad_receiver);
    super.onPause();

    server.cancel();
    restoreBTDeviceName();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button btn = (Button) v;
    if (btn.getId() == R.id.button_start) {
        if (!myBluetoothAdapter.getName().startsWith(PREFIX))
            myBluetoothAdapter.setName(PREFIX );

        if (myBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
            requestBTDiscoverable();
            server = new AcceptThread();
            server.start();

            btn.setEnabled(false);

            ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button_stop)).setEnabled(true);
        }
    } else if (btn.getId() == R.id.button_stop) {
        server.cancel();
        btn.setEnabled(false);
        ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button_start)).setEnabled(true);

        restoreBTDeviceName();
    }

}

/**
 * Launches Discoverable Bluetooth Intent.
 */
public void requestBTDiscoverable() {
    Intent i = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    i.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);

    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST);

    int result = 0;

    this.onActivityResult(REQUEST, result, i);
    Log.i(TAG, "Bluetooth discoverability enabled");
}

/**
 * Obtains the Vibrator service.
 *
 * @return Vibrator Object.
 */
private Vibrator getVibrator() {

    return (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
}

/**
 * Removes the prefix from the device name if the prefix is present.
 */
private void restoreBTDeviceName() {
    if (myBluetoothAdapter.getName().startsWith(PREFIX))
        myBluetoothAdapter.setName(myBluetoothAdapter.getName().substring(PREFIX.length()));
}

/**
 * Shows a information dialog.
 *
 * @param message  String resource used to define the message.
 * @param duration Dialog's TTL.
 */
private void showInformation(String message, long duration) {
    final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(this);

    TextView txt = new TextView(this);
    txt.setText(message);
    mDialog.setContentView(txt);
    mDialog.setTitle("Information");
    mDialog.show();

    (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
    },duration); // Close dialog after delay
}


/**
 * ************************************* AcceptThread *************************************
 */
class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    /**
     * Tag that will appear in the log.
     */
    private final String ACCEPT_TAG = AcceptThread.class.getName();

    /**
     * The bluetooth server socket.
     */
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = myBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(ACCEPT_TAG, UUID.fromString(defaultUUID));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        while (true) {
            try {
                Log.i(ACCEPT_TAG, "Listening for a connection...");

                socket = mServerSocket.accept();
                Log.i(ACCEPT_TAG, "Connected to " + socket.getRemoteDevice().getName());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                try {
                    // Read the incoming string.
                    String buffer;

                    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                    buffer = in.readUTF();

                    Intent i = new Intent(MESSAGE_RECEIVED_INTENT);
                    i.putExtra("Message", String.format("%sn From: %s", buffer, socket.getRemoteDevice().getName()));

                    getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(i);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(ACCEPT_TAG, "Error obtaining InputStream from socket");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    mServerSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Will cancel the listening socket, and cause the thread to finish
     */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sufian thanks for formatting would you please like to help me out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first line of LogCat says:

> Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

It simply means that you need to check the API documentation of [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for help, which says:

> ***Note:***    If registering a receiver in your `Activity.onResume()` implementation, you should unregister it in `Activity.onPause()`. (You won't receive intents when paused, and this will cut down on unnecessary system overhead). Do not unregister in `Activity.onSaveInstanceState()`, because this won't be called if the user moves back in the history stack.

Comment: please check my onPause() method the first line of the method is unregisterReceiver(this.broad_receiver) I have change some thing in my code which was registering Broadcast in onResume() it had solved my problem but my android app is not receiving a message of the PC server any idea or any link to get the solution??

Comment: If you replace the `this.finish();` line with `return;`, does it still crash? What does the LogCat say?

Comment: I am not testing on emulator because for bluetooth it require setup I am testing it on Actual device and I don't think it will have any effect because I have adaptor in mobile.

Comment: @WaseemFarooqui what fixed the issue?

Comment: yes I have fixed the issue I was basically problem with emulator that it wa leaking it is working pretty much fine in mobile application and I have removed     registerReceiver() from     onResume() and place it in     onCreate()